# Get LTE RSRQ, SINR, CQI, CINR and Handover informations in Android Studio

Tags: android, lte, network-monitoring

I searched very much before posting this question. I'm working on `LTE network` monitoring and drive testing on `Android Studio`. 
I found a way to measure `RSRP`, `Asu Level` and other `LTE network` measurements using methods `getCellSignalStrength()` and `getCellIdentity()` from the class `CellInfo`. However, `I am still searching for a manner to determine or calculate RSRQ, CQI, SINR, SNR, HO total attempts and HO successful attempts`.
I'll be grateful if anyone can provide me with the answer !

This is what I tried:

```
    //start the signal strength listener
    signalStrengthListener = new SignalStrengthListener();

    ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


    try {
        cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 1: " + e);
    }

    try {
        for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
            if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                // gets RSRP cell signal strength:
                cellSig = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();

                // Gets the LTE cell indentity: (returns 28-bit Cell Identity, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                cellID = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getCi();

                // Gets the LTE MCC: (returns 3-digit Mobile Country Code, 0..999, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                cellMcc = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getMcc();

                // Gets theLTE MNC: (returns 2 or 3-digit Mobile Network Code, 0..999, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                cellMnc = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getMnc();

                // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();

                // Gets the LTE TAC: (returns 16-bit Tracking Area Code, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                cellTac = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getTac();


            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("SignalStrength", "++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 2: " + e);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try{
        if(signalStrengthListener != null){tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);}
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try{
        if(signalStrengthListener != null){tm.listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_NONE);}
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener{

    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {

        ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(signalStrengthListener, SignalStrengthListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        /*
        int a = tm.getNetworkType();
        CellLocation cl = tm.getCellLocation();
        String did = tm.getDeviceId();
        String sv = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
        String netOp = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
        */




        String ltestr = signalStrength.toString();
        String[] parts = ltestr.split(" ");
        String cellSig2 = parts[9];

        try {
            cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
            for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
                if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    // cast to CellInfoLte and call all the CellInfoLte methods you need
                    // gets RSRP cell signal strength:
                    cellSig = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength().getDbm();

                    // Gets the LTE cell identity: (returns 28-bit Cell Identity, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                    cellID = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getCi();

                    // Gets the LTE MCC: (returns 3-digit Mobile Country Code, 0..999, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                    cellMcc = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getMcc();



                    // Gets theLTE MNC: (returns 2 or 3-digit Mobile Network Code, 0..999, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                    cellMnc = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getMnc();

                    // Gets the LTE PCI: (returns Physical Cell Id 0..503, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                    cellPci = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getPci();

                    // Gets the LTE TAC: (returns 16-bit Tracking Area Code, Integer.MAX_VALUE if unknown)
                    cellTac = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getTac();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SignalStrength", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ null array spot 3: " + e);
        }

        signalStrengthTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellSig));
        signalStrengthTextView2.setText(String.valueOf(cellSig2));
        cellIDTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellID));
        cellMccTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellMcc));
        cellMncTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellMnc));
        cellPciTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellPci));
        cellTacTextView.setText(String.valueOf(cellTac));

        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @A.Belta Hi. hope you are doing well. Did you find the solution for this?